# How can I allow HTTP Methods on Nginx

Tags: http, nginx, post, methods, get

I am trying to pass some HTTP methods. Post and Get methods also are working but when I have tried to Head Method, I always get this output.

```
405 Method Not Allowed
Connection: close
Date: Wed, 29 Jan 2020 08:37:05 GMT
Server: Kestrel
Allow: GET
Client-Date: Wed, 29 Jan 2020 08:37:05 GMT
Client-Peer: 127.0.0.1:5000
Client-Response-Num: 1
```

My researches on the internet did not work. How can I solve this problem?

Here is my conf. file.

```
server {
listen        80;
server_name   xtest.com *.xtest.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}

    location ~ ^/api/(.*)$ {
        proxy_pass       http://localhost:5000/$1;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

     add_header Allow "GET, POST, HEAD" always;
     if ( $request_method !~ ^(GET|POST|HEAD)$ ) {
        return 405 http://localhost:5000;
     }
```

Thanks for your help,

Regards,

Comment: From the response, it seems to be originating from the Kestrel server, not Nginx.

Comment: thank you @RichardSmith, Now I sure why I still got the error.